# How to correctly pass math functions for orderBy function in knex.js?

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

I am trying to pass in simple math function to sql server, using knex.js. I would like to order a list of items by the following code,

```
.orderBy(
`abs(location.mapCoordinatesX-${Number(filter.location.mapCoordinatesX)}) 
+ 
abs(location.mapCoordinatesY - ${Number(filter.location.mapCoordinatesY)})`,
'ASC')
```

I get the following error

```
"select * from `event` where (`status` = 'live') and (`range` = 'global') order by `{abs(location`.`mapCoordinatesX - 52`.`278270) + abs(location`.`mapCoordinatesY - 20`.`869495)}` ASC - SQLITE_ERROR: near \".\": syntax error"
```

From what I can see knex treats the second value, not an integer but as a reference to tables. I am not sure how I can escape this.

I have tested, the orderby function directly in the sql and its correct 
here is the sql query i am trying to replicate in Knex

```
select * from `event` inner join `location` on `event`.`id` = `location`.`event_id` Order By abs(location.mapCoordinatesX- 52.278270) + abs(location.mapCoordinatesY - 20.869495) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

nevermind ... 
You can use orderByRaw to bypass this problem